# Way to do a batch update and insert

Tags: sql, batch-file

I'm looking for some tips and things to consider for this issue.
I'm getting thousands of records from a web services call. 
Relevant data items are id, startDate, termDate, name, and some other fields.
There is a db populated with some records.
Uniqueness is id + startDate + termDate, note that there may be many same ids, with differing startDate and/or termDate.

For the records from the web services call, I need to find the records that match on the unique constraint, and for those records, do an update. 
For records from the web services that are NOT in the db (id + startDate + termDate), i need to insert the record.

The application currently uses iBatis.
I need some direction on a good way to do the 'does the record exist' exist routine, and how to keep track of the web services records that need to be used for an update vs. an insert.

Then, once I have these two sets of reocrds, I'm wondering what is best way to do the db work.
Is it best to iterate over once record at a time and do the work (insert or update), or is it a better idea to make one big update or insert string that has all of the records in it, so in effect, i would have two db calls, one for update and one for insert (but the sql would be huge)?

Answer (score 1):

Save the records from the web service in a text file. Then do a batch insert into an empty temporary table. The code will vary according to the rdbms.

Once you have the temporary table do the insert:

```
insert into my_table (id, startDate, termDate, name)
select t.id, t.startDate, t.termDate, t.name
from temp_table t
left outer join my_table my on 
    t.id = my.id
    and
    t.startDate = my.startDate
    and
    t.termDate = my.termDate
where my.id is null
```

And the update:

```
update my_table
set 
    id = t.id, 
    startDate = t.startDate, 
    termDate = t.termDate, 
    name = t.name
from temp_table t
inner join my_table my on 
    t.id = my.id
    and
    t.startDate = my.startDate
    and
    t.termDate = my.termDate
where 
    id = t.id
    and
    startDate = t.startDate
    and 
    termDate = t.termDate
```

The not tested update syntax above should work in postgresql. If you specify the rdbms I could change it.